# Vim user considering Sublime

Tags: text-editors, vim

I've been using vim mostly happily for a few years now.  I'm a pretty advanced user, to the point of creating my own addons.  I recently heard about the [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/features) text editor.  What features of sublime might be particularly attractive to me?  What might I miss from vim?

Comment: I use Sublime for Windows (and love Textmate on Mac) and Sublime is pretty good.  It doesn't feel as extensible as Textmate, or at least not as intuitively but I have no real complaints about it.  I am not a VIM user though so I can't tell you what you would miss from VIM, other than having to use the Mouse more. :)

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to why this question was a) migrated from programmers.se and b) closed.  Compare with http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/83688/why-would-you-use-vi-vim

Comment: Mainly because these sites are getting more popular, and different people are gaining abilities that give them the power to change things, but they don't necessarily all agree on a specific way to run things.  I.E. the more popular it gets, the more fragmented the standards get.